Update a certain document that is inside a subcollection that is inside more than one document
I have firebase collection named collection1 that has many documents. Each of these documents has a subcollection named collection2 that has many documents. Each document has a few fields.
I need to update one field (it has unique name) inside one document (it has a unique ID) inside the collection2 for ALL documents inside collection1.
Thanks.
Every time, I access colection1 documents, I get zero documents because as you know we cannot access documents that has nested subcollection.


We cannot access documents that has nested subcollection

That's not true.
You just probably don't actually have any documents in collection1.  If the document IDs are shown in italics in the console, that means the documents don't exist and can't be queried, and that makes your task seem impossible.  However, you can certainly create these documents anyway (they don't need to contain any fields), and it in no way affects what happens to the nested documents.  Everything still works the same, except you can now query the existing documents in collection1, iterate them, then use that to find the collection2 documents.
Or you can instead do a collection group query on collection2 to find the documents to update.  It sounds like you need to filter the collection group query by document ID to find the ones to update.  You'll need to add the document ID as a field on subcollection2 documents, as described here:

How to perform collection group query using document ID in Cloud Firestore
Firestore collection group query on document id


Thank you so much! Yes, the docIDs are in italic. I have collection2 documents with a field that has the docID. But I need to go through all documents in colection1 that are in italic. Can you point me in he right direction

I gave you two possible solutions in my answer.  Please read it again and pick the one you're willing to implement.  You will have to do something to change your data.

I added an extra field in the italic documents, it became real and then I could retrieve them and access them. Thanks!

Yes, it is helpful and I marked it as helpful.
